# Why each in jQuery don't iterate all value across list

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

In this function part $.each iterate just trought first value and then stop. I have similar part code with $.each and that code work ok, I do not understand what is problem in this case.

```
function play(j,list1,list2){
      var t1=list1.map(function(g){return g.length})

  var t2=list2.map(function(g){return g.length})

  var case1=-1;
  var case2=-1;
  var case3=-1;
  var case4=-1;
  var case5=-1;
  var i=0;

 $.each(list1,function(index,value){
   console.log(index);
    i=index;

    if(t1[i]==1 && t2[i]==3){
      case1=i;
    }
    else if(t2[i]==1 && t1[i]==3){
      case2=i;
    }
    else if(t[i]==2 && t2[i]==3){
     case3=i;
    }
    else if(t[i]==3 && t2[i]==3){
     case4=i;
    }
    else if(t1[i]>=0 && t2[i]>=1){case5=i;}
else{}
  });
```

Comment: And what does `list1` look like ?

Comment: Can you be less descriptive with your variable names?

Comment: Where is the argument  `j`  utilized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the javascript console, you probably have the error saying that `t` is not defined.

You have `t1` and `t2`, but in your code you also use `t`:

```
else if(t[i]==2 && t2[i]==3){
   case3=i;
}
else if(t[i]==3 && t2[i]==3){
   case4=i;
}
```

Comment: @AleksandarPetrovic I am glad that it helped, please mark the answer as "accepted", so others coming here will know that the solution is found.